# Android Studio telnet console missing "network" and "window" command?

Tags: android, console, android-emulator, telnet

I'm trying to play around with connecting to an Android emulator through telnet, following the guidance of this page: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-console.html

I successfully connected to localhost:5554, authenticated with the token found in `/Users/me/.emulator_console_auth_token`, and got a list of available commands:

```
$ telnet localhost 5554
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Android Console: Authentication required
Android Console: type 'auth <auth_token>' to authenticate
Android Console: you can find your <auth_token> in 
'/Users/me/.emulator_console_auth_token'
OK
auth 123456789XYZ
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
help
Android console command help:

    help|h|?         print a list of commands
    crash            crash the emulator instance
    kill             kill the emulator instance
    quit|exit        quit control session
    redir            manage port redirections
    power            power related commands
    event            simulate hardware events
    avd              control virtual device execution
    finger           manage emulator fingerprint
    geo              Geo-location commands
    sms              SMS related commands
    cdma             CDMA related commands
    gsm              GSM related commands
    rotate           rotate the screen by 90 degrees
```

However, I noticed that `network`, `window` and `vm` commands mentioned in that page are not in this list. How do I get to run those commands?

Thank you very much in advance!

Matt

Answer (score 0):

this option is available while running the emulator in android studio 2.3.1